# Docker filling up my SSD with containers when I stop an AWS server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I'm working on an AWS server with 50GB of SSD. I have a docker instance installed that I boot up to do some training. Several times I have "Stopped" the instance when I am not training (while the docker is still up) and then I start up the instance later.

When run `sudo docker ps` my old docker container is gone and so I have to start up a new one. I work with about 8-10GB of information while using the container. When I booted up my server today I found that it had 44/50GB full on disk, but when I run `du -sh` in the root directory I only get 8.9G listed and when I browse in the couple of folders I have made I can only find about 8.0G on disk.

I am wondering if when I stop the AWS server if it writes the docker container I had to disk and if so is there anyway I can restart these or delete them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are running `docker run` each time to start the container. That will result in multiple containers on your instance.

`sudo docker ps` will only display running containers. To see all containers, you need to run `sudo docker ps -a`. After starting your instance if you run the command with the `-a` flag, you can see the container that was running when you shut the instance down.

Once you see the desired container, you can just restart it with `sudo docker start <container>`.